# 'User' is not a assignable to type 'void'

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, ionic4

I've been stuck for months with Ionic 4 and Firestore.  Once I went to Firestore and Ionic 4 lots of things broke so I'm starting from scratch.  I'm following the AngularFirebase Ionic Google Login for iOS and Android Youtube tutorial and I'm getting the following error:

[ng] ERROR in src/app/pages/login/login.page.ts(35,7): error TS2322: Type 'User' is not assignable to type 'void'.

I'm using the exact same code as in the tutorial but not sure why I'm getting this error.

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
    import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
    import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
    import { GooglePlus } from '@ionic-native/google-plus/ngx';
    import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss'],
})
export class LoginPage  {

  user: Observable<firebase.User>;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
               private gplus: GooglePlus) {

        this.user = this.afAuth.authState;
      }
  googleLogin() {
    this.nativeGoogleLogin();
  }

    async nativeGoogleLogin(): Promise<void> {
      try {

      const gplusUser = await this.gplus.login({
        'webClientId': environment.googleWebClientId,
        'offline': true,
        'scopes': 'profile email'
      });

           return await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithCredential(
         firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider.credential(gplusUser.idToken)
      );

          } catch (err) {
              console.log(err);
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: What's at line number: 35 ?? Is it  `firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider.credential(gplusUser.idToken)` ??

Comment: Yes. It's using the token it receives 7 lines above to sign in using that token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`signInWithCredential` is returning a `firebase.User` object, so you can change the return type for your function to `Promise<firebase.User>`.

```
async nativeGoogleLogin(): Promise<firebase.User> {
      try {

      const gplusUser = await this.gplus.login({
        'webClientId': environment.googleWebClientId,
        'offline': true,
        'scopes': 'profile email'
      });

           return await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithCredential(
         firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider.credential(gplusUser.idToken)
      );

          } catch (err) {
              console.log(err);
          }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never written a line of Angular so bear with me. However I've written some Typescript.

You've(or the author of this tutorial) set the return type of this Promise to void and you're returning a user if the login is successful or void if the login fails

`async nativeGoogleLogin(): Promise<void> { ... }`

This returns some type of user object

```
return await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithCredential(
   firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider.credential(gplusUser.idToken)
);
```

Try to update the return value of your method to either a User or void(for the catch)

```
async nativeGoogleLogin(): Promise<firebase.User | void> {
    try {

    const gplusUser = await this.gplus.login({
        'webClientId': environment.googleWebClientId,
        'offline': true,
        'scopes': 'profile email'
    });

    return await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithCredential(
        firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider.credential(gplusUser.idToken)
    );

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```